# Java: override Enum.name value

Tags: java, enums

I want to refactor my enums in the following way: I have enums with method for getting its String value:

```
public enum Type {
    TYPE_1("Type 1"),
    TYPE_2("Type 2");

    private String value;
    Type(String value) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I want to get its value simply by `toString()` method call. According to `java.lang.Enum` code `toString` is defined as

```
public String toString() {
    return this.name;
}
```

So I guessed all I needed was to redefine name variable in my class:

```
public enum Type {
    TYPE_1("Type 1"),
    TYPE_2("Type 2");

    private String name;
    Type(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

But according to debugger there are 2 name variables: in my Type class and in Enum superclass, so `toString()` returns `Enum.name`

My question is can I return `Type.name` in `Enum.toString()` value without redefining it in subclass?

Comment: Just override `toString` and return `value` (which you have to properly initialize in your constructor in that first snippet).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis yes, I know it would work, but I want to know if I can use Enum.toString() method for it

Comment: Everything related with Enum.name is private or final. So you can override it. The way to go is explained above, overriding toString() in your class.